# Mac OSX: Running a script that that avoids the need to input the sudo password and that closes the Terminal at the end of execution

Tags: macos, terminal, command, skype

So just to give a bit of context: Skype on Mac is a bit of a mess right now and I've recently ran into an issue where it would not let me login at all (it keeps saying I'm already logged into some other account and gets stuck there - even signing out, reinstalling Skype and clearing local app data won't work).

Anyway, the only way to get it running that I found is by running this in terminal:

- Step 1: cd /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/
- Step 2: sudo ./Skype
- Step 3: Enter password

(basically opens another instance of Skype which for some reason does let me login)

Long story short, I'd like to make this process as quick and easy as possible, ideally by double-clicking an app icon which runs the above script. I'd like to make it so that it doesn't require a password input in terminal and preferably closes the terminal windows after it starts Skype.

I've been looking into putting the above commands into a .command script which works nicely, but the terminal windows remain open (tried adding an exit command) and it still requires the password (I've been looking into editing the sudoers file to make an exception to the Skype command but obviously messing in there is a bad idea for someone without experience).

If you guys have some suggestions on how to go about this that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason your *Step 2* works is probably that the new instance of Skype is running as a different user - i.e. the root user so it doesn't appear to Skype that one user is running 2 copies.

Comment: Try using `sudo ./skype &` at Step 2.

Comment: Using sudo ./skype & at Step 2 doesn't seem to do anything I'm afraid. Anyway, it seems you're right about forcing Skype run two instances of itself - maybe that's a clue into fixing the issue in the first place. Maybe there's some other user-related settings/data that Skype saves somewhere , and perhaps clearing them might fix the issue. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Setchell's comment I got the idea to use App Cleaner in order to uninstall Skype (rather that the typical move to trash & delete its files from the AppData directory) and it seems like this did the trick. Whatever cached data or setting was causing the original issue must've been saved somewhere else, and AppCleaner manager to clear all of it.

Reinstalling a fresh copy of Skype worked fine afterwards. Thanks for the help!

Cheers